# Prevent form submit in certain cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I have my FineUploader working great except for 1 scenario. There are cases where one of my form elements (such as a textbox or pulldown) has invalid data. I want to prevent the upload from occurring in this case. Somehow FineUploader is circumventing my form validation and submitting anyway, as long as a valid image has been selected. Here is my form tag:

```
<form action="./fine-uploader/server/endpoint.php" id="qq-form" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
```

My `checkForm()` function correctly returns true/false back to the `onSubmit` of the form. When it returns false, normally that would prevent the form from submitting, but as long as FineUploader has a valid image (selected by user), it submits in all cases, even when checkForm() returns false.

I have already tried this:

```
form: { interceptSubmit: false},
```

That works, but it has an awful side effect: rather than submitting the form async, it redirects to my php handler (I suppose it's doing a form GET or POST) rather than doing a nice async submission.

I simply need a way to prevent form submission at times of my choosing, and enable form submission when wanted.

Here are my settings currently:

```
<script>
    var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: './fine-uploader/server/endpoint.php'
        },
        thumbnails: {
            placeholders: {
                waitingPath: './fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                notAvailablePath: './fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
            }
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
            itemLimit: 1,
            sizeLimit: 307200 // 300 kB = (300kb * 1024 bytes) = 307200
        },
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON) {
                if (responseJSON.success === true) {
                    //location.href = "ManageAds.php";
                    location.href = "index.php";
                } else {
                    console.log(responseJSON);
                    //history.go(0);
                }

                //console.log(responseJSON.success);
            },
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        debug: false,
        multiple: false
    });

    qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
        manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
    });
</script>
```

How can I prevent form submission when one of my validators fails? If you have something elegant and built into FineUploader, great. If not, I'll be happy with any type of hack, I just need to get this working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since setCustomValidity throws runtime exceptions inside fine-uploader.js, the best way I could find to prevent fine-uploader from continuing with the upload in the midst of custom validation problem was to do this:

```
_uploadStoredFiles: function() { // find this line in fine-uploader.js
    if(!zgpValidationOK){ // add a var of your choice, set to true upstream
        return; // if var above becomes false in custom code, return now
    }
```

Works great for me.

Comment: This is not a wise choice, and I would not suggest ever modifying third party code in your app without having a very strong understanding of that code. Your claim that a web API method throws errors in fine Uploader doesn't really make much sense. This is likely due to issues in your code. Since you haven't demonstrated your code, there is no way to help further. Also, your suggestion involves modifying fine Uploader code without really understanding the consequences of this action. I strongly discourage this. Instead, demonstrate the issue you are having so that can be solved.

Comment: Ray, nothing you have stated on this post has been helpful in the least. Your suggestion didn't work, and your 2 sanctimonious assertions about things NEVER to do are both silly. Onsubmit has been around forever and lots of sites/developers use it. If it were something that should "never" be done, browser makers would remove it -- yet none of them have. Also, if tweaking 3rd party code is the only thing that works, I'm going to do it. You can go back to your ivory tower now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an inline `onSubmit` event handler (which you should *never* use), make use of the [Constraints API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation). This standard allows you to specify custom restrictions per form field. You can also watch changes to your elements and update validity pragmatically using the `setCustomValidity` method. All of this is provided by the HTML5 web specification, and represents a modern way to handle form validation. Fine Uploader will respect any such constraints.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of how to prevent FineUploader from submitting?

Comment: Fine Uploader isn't a factor here. Take a look at the constraints API docs I linked to. You can set per-field constraints that, if violated, will prevent the form submit.

Comment: I did read that and it doesn't help with my scenario. I was already using those per-field constraints, which are fine for very simplistic things. But I have constraints that require custom javascript programming to determine whether a violation has occurred. I need a way to instruct the browser to not submit the form based on custom rules. Also, simply linking to another page without providing a specific example is considered bad practice on stack overflow because it's often not helpful. Examples are best.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can set more complex restrictions by monitoring changes in your fields and calling setCustomValidity on the form or field as needed. The document I linked to covers this as well. Furthermore, it is not required to supply code in an answer. As you can see, I've been supplying answers on SO for quite a long time. Your question was vague and left out the specific validation you are looking to enforce. If you update your question with specifics, I will consider updating my answer with specific code.

Comment: setCustomValidity throws runtime exceptions inside fine-uploader.js.

Comment: All JavaScript errors are runtime errors. And I would guess that if you are seeing issues, it is due to incorrect code on your end. You haven't shown your attemp so I can't provide any help.